# Indy OnExecute first Read slow

Tags: delphi, c++builder, indy, indy10

I have the following code in my OnExecute in C++ Builder XE:

```
void __fastcall Test::TestExecute( TIdContext* AContext )
{
   try
   {
      // get the command directive
      DWORD startTime = timeGetTime( );
      UnicodeString DBCommand = AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadChar();
      DWORD endTime = timeGetTime();
      UnicodeString log;
      log.printf( L"getting command %d ms", endTime - startTime );
      Log( log );
      ...
```

The log starts at getting command 100 milliseconds and creeps to 300 where it sits for the rest of the application run.  I thought that `OnExecute` was called once data was in the buffer, so why would it take 100 to 300 ms for the first read to succeed?

After this first read in the same `OnExecute` all other data is read very very quickly (millisecond to sub millisecond).

What could be going wrong?

EDIT:

at method launch: `AContext->Connection->IOHandler->InputBuffer->Size` is 0.  After the first read returns `AContext->Connection->IOHandler->InputBuffer->Size` contains whats left int he buffer after the read.  So this implies that `OnExecute` is called before any data is actually available to the caller.  So the 100-300 ms is the amount of time its taking Indy to fetch the data from the socket and place it in the Buffer after it get notification that data is arriving.  That seems way too long.

EDIT:

removed `do{` as it was implying a loop that was not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OnExecute` event is not tied to the socket buffer at all.  `TIdTCPServer` begins calling `OnExecute` immeidately after the `OnConnect` event is called, and continues calling `OnExecute` in an endless loop until the client disconnects (in other words, you should NOT be looping yourself inside of your `OnExecute` handler.  Read a packet, process, exit, wait for the next event, repeat).

You are correct that the `InputBuffer` can grow larger than what you are asking for in code.  All of the `IOHandler`'s reading methods get their data from the `InputBuffer` only, not the socket directly. If the `InputBuffer` does not have enough bytes cached to satisfy a read request, the `IOHandler` will then wait for bytes to be available on the socket, and will then read all of the bytes into the `InputBuffer` for later use.  This minimizes how often the socket needs to be accessed, and help keep the socket responsive to new data.

Comment: Sorry, the `do{` was implying a loop that did not exist.  I do not loop in the `OnExecute`, I use `do{}while(false);` to exit out early.  `OnExecute is called when data arrives, is that correct?  But it still takes 100 to 300 ms to get the first data after `OnExecute` is called. I don't recall this occurring in C++ Builder 2010.

Comment: No, `OnExecute` is not called when data arrives.  As I said, it is called immediately after `OnConnect` exits, and is called in an endless loop for the lifetime of the connection, regardless of any data.  It is the `OnExecute` handler's responsibility to manage data operations as needed.  When `OnExecute` is called, `TIdTCPServer` expects the handler to block the calling thread as needed, yielding when needed, but `TIdTCPServer` itself does nothing more beyond that.  As for any differences between 2010 and XE, there were no changes in Indy regarding this. It has always worked this way.

Comment: Right, I misunderstood your first post.  The 'regardless of any data' solves the problem for me.